# Relations between Room Tables Android

Tags: java, android, android-room

I am developping a chat app. I have two Entities

```
@Entity(tableName = "messages")
public class MessageItem {
    @PrimaryKey
    private Integer msgId;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "from_id")
    private String  contact_id; 
}
```

And

```
@Entity(tableName = "contact")
public class Contact{
    @PrimaryKey
    private Integer id;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "contact_phone")
    private String  phone; 
}
```

**In MessageDao I want to get Contact phone correponding to the contact_id in MessageItem**

Comment: You have to implement multi table database in Room. Here is a good playlist for it: https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQkwcJG4YTCS3AD2C-yWtJUGTYMh5h3Zz

Comment: interesting videos, but I am a little be lost with the explanations. If you can for my case give a specific answer that would be very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three ways you can do this.

**1)** You can use a POJO with an @Embedded and an @Relation in which case you return MessageItem's with the Contact e.g. :-

```
public class MessageItemWithContact {

    @Embedded
    MessageItem messageItem;
    @Relation(entity = Contact.class, parentColumn = "from_id", entityColumn = "id")
    Contact contact;
}
```

along with an @Query such as :-

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE msgId=:msgId")
MessageItemWithContact getMessageByIdWithContact(int msgId);
```

**2)** Or you can use a POJO with an @Embedded and an additional variable for the phone using a JOIN e.g. :-

```
public class MessageItemWithPhone {
    @Embedded
    MessageItem messageItem;
    String phone;
}
```

Along with an @Query like :-

```
@Query("SELECT msgId, contact_phone, from_id FROM messages JOIN contact On from_id = id  ")
List<MessageItemWithPhone> getMessItemWithContactPhone();
```

- doesn't need @Transaction as the query is a single transaction (whilst the previous method Room obtains the MessageItem and then builds a query to get the related object(s)).
- this query gets all MessageItems (as no WHERE clause has been included)

**3)** Just get the phone using the from_Id for the relevant MessageItem without the need for a POJO by having an @Query like:-

```
@Query("SELECT contact_phone FROM contact WHERE id=:from_Id")
String getPhoneById(String from_Id);
```